# I am trying to make my s3 bucket public for react-native use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a react native application that uploads images to my s3 public. When i first tried to access the images in the bucket, I kept getting Access Denied messages. I went online and found out I can change the policy settings. I tried changing the policy settings but for some reason, it is not working and I keep getting access denied. I am not sure how to fix it.

Here is the policy i am trying to enter to make bucket public:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal" : { "AWS": "*" },
        "Action" : ["s3:GetObject","s3:ListBucket"],
        "Resource" : [ "arn:aws:s3:::seekify-...-staging", "arn:aws:s3:::seekify-...-staging/*"]
    }]
}
```

I am getting the following issue with the policy above:

[image: error]

Here is what my access point looks like:

[image: access point]

I switched the access directly within the bucket and turned off `Block all public access`.

I even switched the access away from `Bucket owner required` but I am still getting the issue of not being able to access the images publicly.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Are you intending to use S3 Access Points?  That's what the error seems to be about

Comment: You should be adding that policy as a Bucket Policy on the bucket itself. Stay away from Access Points unless you have a very specific reason for using them.

Comment: I think that is where i am having trouble, I can not add the policy to the public policy itself. I am getting the same error no matter where I try to impliment the policy. I will try again... @JohnRotenstein

Comment: I switched the bucket to public directly but I still get ```access denied``` when i try to put the url into google and no image shows up. it shows access denied. I even switched it to ```bucket owner preferred``` I will update my question @JohnRotenstein

Comment: If I go into each individual item and make it public, then it works but I dont want to have to do that. is there a way to just make the entire ListImages folder in teh bucket public automatically to Read a List @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a new bucket `sample-bucket-88` with all default settings
- Edited **Permissions** for the bucket and **turned off Block Public Access** for items relating to Bucket Policies:

[image: Edit Block Public Access]

- Added a **Bucket Policy** (based on yours) that permits `GetObject` and `ListBucket` to *anyone:*

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            Principal" : { "AWS": "*" },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sample-bucket-88",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sample-bucket-88/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- Uploaded an image to the S3 bucket (default settings, so no specific ACLs configured)
- Copied the **Object URL** as shown in the S3 console:

```
https://sample-bucket-88.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/image.png
```

- Put that URL in my browser -- **it worked!**

You might want to compare your configuration to the above to see where it differs.